# Toggle an active class - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to add an active class to a selected div.  Currently I cannot get it to drop the active class when it is deselected

```js
var item = $('.item').click(function() {
  item.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$(".item").on("click", function(e) {
  //get curent description
  let $desc = $(this).next(".desc");
  // hide all other description execpt current
  $(".desc").not($desc).hide();
  // show or hide current description
  $desc.css("display") == "none" ? $desc.show() : $desc.hide();
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

.item,
.desc {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.active {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 6</div>
</div>
```

I want to add the active class to the selected description box - I cannot get this to properly remove the active class, even if I add it to the function to toggle the description

Comment: It seems to work in the snippet.

Comment: Note that `$('.item').click(function () {...` and `$('.item').on('click', function(e) {...` both do the same thing...

Comment: @Barmar If you make a selection and then click it again, the OP wants to remove the class to de-select it

Comment: I'd just use [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass1) myself...

Answer (score 0):

to do that You need to  exclude the clicked item from the list to remove active class from
use  this

```
  $('.item').not(this).removeClass('active');
```

or you can use siblings too if there are no other elements with the boxes with numbers

```
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
```

which ever you feel better

```js
var item = $('.item').click(function(){
        
        $('.item').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
    
    $(".item").on("click", function(e) { 
      //get curent description
      let $desc = $(this).next(".desc");
      // hide all other description execpt current
      $(".desc").not($desc).hide();
      // show or hide current description
      $desc.css("display") == "none" ? $desc.show() : $desc.hide();  
    })
```

```css
.container {
      width: 95%;
      margin: auto;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
      grid-auto-flow: row dense;
      grid-gap: 0.5em;
    }
    
    .item, 
    .desc {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      height: 100px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    
    .desc {
      display: none;
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }
    
    .active {
      background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
          <div class="item">1</div>
          <div class="desc">Description 1</div>
          <div class="item">2</div>
          <div class="desc">Description 2</div>
          <div class="item">3</div>
          <div class="desc">Description 3</div>
          <div class="item">4</div>
          <div class="desc">Description 4</div>
          <div class="item">5</div>
          <div class="desc">Description 5</div>
          <div class="item">6</div>
          <div class="desc">Description 6</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it similarly to the way you handle the description field. Remove the class from all the other items, and toggle the class of the selected item.

You can also use the `.toggle()` function rather than checking CSS for the description.

```js
var item = $('.item').click(function() {
  item.not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(".item").on("click", function(e) {
  //get curent description
  let $desc = $(this).next(".desc");
  // hide all other description execpt current
  $(".desc").not($desc).hide();
  // show or hide current description
  $desc.toggle();
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

.item,
.desc {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.active {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```js
var item = $('.item');
var desc = $('.desc');

item.on("click", function(e) {
  item.removeClass('active');
  desc.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).next('.desc').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

.item,
.desc {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.desc.active {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="desc">Description 1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="desc">Description 2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="desc">Description 3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="desc">Description 4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="desc">Description 5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="desc">Description 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would condense the logic to a single event handler.  You can toggle the class on the element clicked first to add/remove the active.  Then you can filter on all the items to find the active one, that is not the one just clicked, to remove it from any others, if the one clicked was just marked as active.

```js
var $items = $('.item').on('click', function(e) {
  $(e.target).toggleClass('active');
  $items.filter('.active').not(e.target).removeClass('active');
  

  //get curent description
  let $desc = $(e.target).next(".desc");
  
  // hide all other description execpt current
  $(".desc").not($desc).hide();
  
  // show or hide current description
  $desc.toggle();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

.item,
.desc {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.active {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $items = $('.item').on('click', function(e) {
  $(e.target).toggleClass('active');
  $items.filter('.active').not(e.target).removeClass('active');
  

  //get curent description
  let $desc = $(e.target).next(".desc");
  
  // hide all other description execpt current
  $(".desc").not($desc).hide();
  
  // show or hide current description
  $desc.toggle();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

.item,
.desc {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.active {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="desc">Description 6</div>
</div>
```